# Custom Build Process in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, build, build-process

I'm currently having to use a really old IDE to build apps for my calculator in C. but i just noticed that all the IDE does is run a .bat file to compile the app.

Is there a way to customize the build process in visual studio to run the same file etc rather than the default c compiler?

Comment: It is most likely possible. But even if I did figure out how to do it, if you are trying to debug with Visual Studio after compiling with an external compiler it will most likely not work. You ok with that?

Comment: Yeah, if i really needed to debug id just use the old IDE, i just want to be able to click build in visual studio and have a .bat file run instead of the C compiler. And at a push, possibly have the output of the bat file be visible in the vs output window

Comment: Which VS are you using?

Comment: VS2017, im wondering if i could write a makefile to achieve what i want?

Comment: If your project is a "makefile" project, sure.